# Find and update an object in an array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I want to get an object from an array of objects, then update it.

```
var myObjs = [{ id: 1, name: "foo"}, { id: 2, name: "bar" }];

var myObjectToUpdate = _.findWhere(myObjs, { id: 2 });

myObjectToUpdate = { id: 2, name: "boop" };

myObjs[1] // { id: 2, name: "boop" }
```

Currently when I update myObject in the 3rd line, it does not update the array of objects. I'm assuming it is updating the new variable instead of referencing.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You've reassigned your `myObjectToUpdate` variable in the 3rd line. It will not affect the one retrieved from the array. JavaScript references are copied by value.

Comment: Wow, obvious now - thank you :)

Comment: looks like someone blasted this question & answers with downvotes, instead of using "close". sorry guys :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@E_net4 is correct, you are reassigning the object you just found.

If all you need to do is update the name, try this:

```
var myObjs = [{ id: 1, name: "foo"}, { id: 2, name: "bar" }];

var myObjectToUpdate = _.findWhere(myObjs, { id: 2 });

myObjectToUpdate.name = "boop";

myObjs[1] // { id: 2, name: "boop" }
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess this is what you want. You have, in your code, misconceptions. Please read my code and compare both.

Hope it helps!

```
function fn(arr, toReplace, newValue) {
  for(var x in arr) {
    for(var k in toReplace) {
      if(arr[x][k] == toReplace[k]) {
        arr[x] = newValue;
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
};

var arr = [{ id: 1, name: "foo"}, { id: 2, name: "bar" }];
var newValue = {id: 2, name: "boop"};

arr = fn(arr, {id: 2}, newValue);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: It would be useful if explain why the downvote... is what he want to do.

Comment: Providing a new piece of code without stating the root of the problem and simply avoiding underscore when it is tagged in the question does seem to make a poor answer.